# Using `this` in a loop to target current item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jsfiddle set up with my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7MjN6/

As you can see, I have two images. I want the divs surrounding each to expand when each is clicked on. I'm attempting to use the `this` object to ensure that clicking on an image only expands that image's div, but I'm sure I'm using `this` wrong because it's not connecting. It would be much appreciated if someone could take a stab at my fiddle!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://blueantlabs.com/wp-content/themes/blueantplate/img/port-wide/thefutureproject-605.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://blueantlabs.com/wp-content/themes/blueantplate/img/port-wide/thefutureproject-605.png" /></a>
    </div>
</body>​
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.img-container').each(function(index){
        var imgHeight = $(" a img").height();
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault;
            $('div').animate({height: imgHeight});
        });
    });     
});​
```

Comment: you aren't using `this` at all.  I even did search on your code and zero occurrences of the word "this"

Comment: That was my mistake, didn't link to the latest fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach. You don't need the `.each` at all:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height(); // use "this", find the img inside
        e.preventDefault(); // this is a method, must use parentheses
        $(this).parent().animate({ // "this" is the anchor; move up to the parent
            height: imgHeight
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7MjN6/4/

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a follow up question: is there an easier way to toggle back than checking the div height each time like here: http://jsfiddle.net/7MjN6/5/ ?

Comment: Use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store the old value before you change it. Give it a try, and if you need more help with it please post  a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$("div").animate(...)` to `$(this).closest("div").animate(...)`. Within the event handler `this` refers to the clicked link. You do not want to expand all divs (which your current version does); you want to expand the div which is wrapping the clicked link. You navigate to that using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).